# Web map graphics and performance optimization

Tags: bing-maps, performance, web

With a web map (in this case, Bing Ajax API v7), what's more important for performance - the number of individual map shapes/graphics drawn on the map, or the total number of vertices drawn on the map?  Put another way, does a single map graphic with 100 vertices use the same amount of resources as 50 map graphics with two vertices each?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer isn't as simple as that. There is an overhead to creating and drawing graphics. So if you have 50 points, then the overhead is much more than one polygon with 50 vertices.

Further more, some of the Web Mapping APIs (Unfortunately I don't know much about the Bing Ajax API, so I can't answer specifically about it) often apply some kind of generalization while displaying graphics with multiple redundant vertices. (The ArcGIS Flex API does this for example).

In my limited experience, I have seen that fewer features/fewer graphics give a better performance.